# Displaying several layered images into an NSView

Tags: image, macos, calayer, nsview

I would like to present several vector images layered on top of each other in my app, and there can be several hundreds of those images. I read that using NSImageViews for that was not a good idea because they are pretty heavy and rendered by the CPU. Instead I should use one NSView with several CALayer sublayers whose contents are my images. But I must be missing something because nothing seems to appears in my NSView. In my storyboard, I have a NSImageView for the background, and on top of that I have an NSView with all the constraints to make give it the same frame as the underlying NSImageView. Then I try to add one of my images to the NSView as a sublayer, but it doesn't seem to be displayed:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapImageView: NSImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var countriesView: NSView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapImageView.image = NSImage(named: "world")?.tint(color: .white)

    countriesView.wantsLayer = true

    let usLayer = CALayer()
    usLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
    usLayer.contents = NSImage(named: "US")
    countriesView?.layer?.addSublayer(usLayer)
}
```

What am I missing?

Note that I don't know if this is relevant but my image is a PDF image.

Comment: “there can be several hundreds of those images” … “my image is a PDF image.” So you have hundreds of PDFs that you want to display on top of each other?

Comment: Well, I'm using PDF as a format of vector image so that it looks good whatever the resolution and shape of the screen, but yes, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: the problem is that I needed to specify a frame for my sublayers

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapImageView: NSImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var countriesView: NSView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapImageView.image = NSImage(named: "world")?.tint(color: .white)

    countriesView.wantsLayer = true

    let usLayer = CALayer()
    usLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
    usLayer.contents = NSImage(named: "US")
    usLayer.frame = countriesView!.layer!.frame
    countriesView?.layer?.addSublayer(usLayer)
}
```